# What all things to consider on replacing a dll - vb.net aspx

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, dll

I am new to .net and got a kind of weird  migration work.

Due to  circumstances i am going to change the functionality of 2 methods in a class and will build and create the dll. If i replace the old dll with new dll , will the application work and will it reflect new functionality in the  server.

I am going to use same file name class name and methods .

What all things i have to consider on replacing the dll? and is it possible to just replace the dll ?

Comment: What's your background? PHP? I'm curious as to where your experience lies such that you don't already know the answer to that question.

Comment: I figured it had to be an environment that didn't use DLLs.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, and in general, yes, you can just replace the DLL. That assumes:

1. You have tested your new code in your Development and QA environments before promoting the changed DLL to your Production environment.
2. You have a rollback plan in case something goes wrong when you deploy to Production
3. Be aware that ASP.NET will allow all current HTTP requests to complete, but will create a new AppDomain in which to load a new copy of the web application, *including the changed DLL*. All subsequent requests will be handled by the new AppDomain. Among other things, this will mean that any `static` variables will be reset to their initial values, and depending on how you have Session state set up, your users may all lose their Session state. This may cause them to be logged out, depending on how you have implemented authentication.

Comment: Thanks ..rollback plan is just to keep the old dll.. its not a high traffic website.. so session issues are not there . i am mainly concerned about the technical details

Comment: So  .net just need the dll , not needed the classes after generating class.  In this case i update class and generate the new dll and put it on the server. But am  not changing the class file. Still it will work

Comment: Assuming this is a Web Application Project (that is, it has a .csproj file), then when you build the classes, it creates the DLL. The .cs files are not necessary, and should not be on the web site. On the other hand, if it's a web site "project", then 1) You should upgrade to a web application project when you get a chance, and 2) The .cs files are left on the site (in the App_Code folder usually). Web site "projects" are strange and should be avoided.